# Line chart using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, linechart, moving-average

I am trying to make a line chart of stock data.
I want to plot three lines on the graph: close, and two running averages.
It's important the lines be thin, something like the [Yahoo finance charts](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=%5EGSPC+Interactive#%7B"showArea":false,"showSma":true,"smaColors":"#cc0000,#009999","smaPeriods":"50,100","smaWidths":"1,1","smaGhosting":"0,0","lineType":"line","allowChartStacking":true%7D).
I saw [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart), but there are a few things I don't see supported.
For example I can't make the lines thinner, I can't set x axis ranges, or have the date shown as X-Axis.

I am looking for recommendations on a good line chart implementation.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [high charts](http://www.highcharts.com/) which has lots of options

Comment: +1 for Highcharts. It sounds like he is plotting stock data, and they also offer Highstocks. http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock